# AVPlayer currentTime is negative value

Tags: ios, iphone, avplayer

I'm using AVPlayer to playing audio files.

But AVPlayer current Time is negative value at start time.

When I use `seek(to: time)` method to move specific time, AVPlayer play about 0.1 seconds before the specific time. (exactly 0.04~0.08)

Does anyone know this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong seek method. Use a seek method where you define a tolerance of 0, so it seeks accurately.

[Documentation for: seek(to:toleranceBefore:toleranceAfter:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer/1387741-seek)

Here's some swift example code to seek to 100 second:

```
avPlayer.seek(to: someCMTime, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero)
```

Comment: No..It's now a answer. It moves 100 but start again 99.92~
I guess it causes mp3 frames.

Comment: Make sure you are using the currect timescale (from your asset) in your CMTime that you're making... 
int32_t timeScale = self.player.currentItem.asset.duration.timescale;
CMTime time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(77.000000, timeScale);

Comment: my code is `self.seek(to: CMTime(seconds: to, preferredTimescale: self.currentTime().timescale))`
I moved 1.2 seconds but play at 1.116897993

Comment: Try using the timescale from the asset of player's currentItem. So something like self.seek(to: CMTime(seconds: to, preferredTimescale: avPlayer.currentItem.asset.duration.timescale))